# Populating textboxes and labels from with specific variables from Listbox or List<T>

Tags: c#

How do i make my code populate a textbox or in this case lblUserId.Text with the variable id? I also want to know how to make this id change everytime i select a different user from my list box which i've named lstEditUser.

```
QueryResult queryResult = null;
String SOQL = "";
SOQL = "select Id, FirstName, LastName, UserRole.Name from user where isactive = true"; /// Pulls All active Users! 2/25/2015 8:30AM
queryResult = Sfdcbinding.query(SOQL);
string id = null;
string firstName = null;
string lastName = null;
string role = null; 


if (queryResult.size > 0)
{               
    for (int i = 0; i < queryResult.size; i++)
    {                    
         User user = (User)queryResult.records[i];
          id = user.Id;
          firstName = user.FirstName;
          lastName = user.LastName;
          role = user.UserRole.Name;
          string[] uSers = { id, firstName, lastName, role };
         listEdit.AddRange(uSers);
         // adds Items in uSers to lstEditUser
         lstEditUser.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}  {1} {2}   {3}", uSers));      
         lstDeleteUser.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}  {1} {2}       {3}",uSers));     

         foreach (var li in listEdit) /// THIS IS WHAT I DONT KNOW HOW TO DO!
         {
             lblUserID.Text = li.Select<string>; /// I WANT IT TO POPULATE THIS LABEL W/ the Variable 'ID' based on the SelectedIndex or Selected Item in the lstEditUser or listEdit
         }

    }
    MessageBox.Show("The query result has found " + queryResult.size  + " users.");

}
else
{
```

Comment: wpf or winforms? or asp.net?

Comment: Basically do what @ASh said and out what ever value you need into the text box

Comment: winforms i think in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to subscribe to lstEditUser.SelectedIndexChanged event and change lblUserID.Text accordingly

```
if (queryResult.size > 0)
{               
    for (int i = 0; i < queryResult.size; i++)
    {                    
         User user = (User)queryResult.records[i];
          id = user.Id;
          firstName = user.FirstName;
          lastName = user.LastName;
          role = user.UserRole.Name;
          string[] uSers = { id, firstName, lastName, role };
         listEdit.AddRange(uSers);
         // adds Items in uSers to lstEditUser
         lstEditUser.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}  {1} {2}   {3}", uSers));      
         lstDeleteUser.Items.Add(string.Format("{0}  {1} {2}       {3}",uSers));     
    }
lstEditUser.SelectedIndexChanged += SelectNewUser;
lstEditUser.SelectedIndex = 0;
    MessageBox.Show("The query result has found " + queryResult.size  + " users.");

}

private void SelectNewUser (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int idx = lstEditUser.SelectedIndex;
    if (idx < 0)
        return;
    lblUserID.Text = listEdit[idx*4];
}
```

Comment: @JT082014, i don't know your full code; i suppose, listEdit is out of scope in SelectNewUser method, try `lblUserID.Text = idx.ToString();` at least."you need to subscribe to  lstEditUser.SelectedIndexChanged event" = "add handler to the event" = `lstEditUser.SelectedIndexChanged += SelectNewUser;`

Comment: OH MY GOD I LOVE YOU!! This finally worked and now i can move on... holy hell. You're awesome dude.

Comment: Last question for you. How do i control the [idx*4] to give me exactly the indexed variable i need for each text box?

Comment: @JT082014, you wrote: `string[] uSers = { id, firstName, lastName, role }; listEdit.AddRange(uSers);` so i decided that listEdit is list of string and i can use `listEdit[idx*4]`; but again, i don't know your full code; idx*4+1 will be firstName, i guess; idx*4+2 will be lastName, idx*4+3 will  be role

Comment: @JT082014, idx*4+1 for firstName, i guess; idx*4+2 for lastName, idx*4+3  for role; the structure of listEdit is {id1, firstName1, lastName1, role1, id2, firstName2, lastName2, role2, etc}, am I right?

Comment: yes you are right. and idx*4+1 for first name worked, as did the one for lastname.. This may be tricky or not even possible but im gonna ask. role wont be populating a text box or a label. i need to know how to make role change a selected index in a list box. so for example if role in listEdit is IT Manager, or Chief Executive Officer, I need lstrole.selectedindex to = IT Manager or Chief Executive Officer. Is this possible??